# Правильное применение open_basedir или как избежать проблем?

Tags: apache, php

Всем привет!

Ситуация такая: необходимо ограничить юзера в его папке, предположим:

```
/var/www/user/
```

Добавляю в конфиг виртуального хоста следующее. Код:

```
...

 DocumentRoot /var/www/user 
 <Directory /> 
     php_admin_value open_basedir /var/www/user 
     Options FollowSymLinks 
     AllowOverride All 
 </Directory> 
 <Directory /var/www/user> 
     php_admin_value open_basedir /var/www/user 
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
     AllowOverride All 
     Order allow,deny 
     allow from all 
 </Directory>

 ...
```

При загрузке скрипта из папки `/var/www/user/` получаю ошибки PHP:

> `[phpBB Debug] PHP Notice: in file /common.php on line 223: require(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File() is not within the allowed path(s): ()
> [phpBB Debug] PHP Notice: in file /portal.php on line 20: include(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File() is not within the allowed path(s): ()`

Answer (score 1):

> > in file /common.php

Вы пытаетесь подключить файл common.php из корня, следовательно получаете ошибку.

Comment: Вот как выглядит проблемная строка:
$phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : './';

И какой вариант решения предложите? Скажу, что скриптов достаточно много.

Comment: Убедитесь, что константа PHPBB_ROOT_PATH объявлена и имеет корректное значение. Перед этой строкой сделайте 

    var_dump(PHPBB_ROOT_PATH);
    exit;

что выведет?

Comment: var_dump(PHPBB_ROOT_PATH); => string(15) "PHPBB_ROOT_PATH"
var_dump(defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH)); => bool(false)

Comment: Ну вот, у вас не задефайнена эта константа.
Где в config файле нужно это сделать.

Comment: Указывал вручную

    $phpbb_root_path = "/"
    $phpbb_root_path = "."
    $phpbb_root_path = "./"
    $phpbb_root_path = "/var/www/user"
    $phpbb_root_path = "/var/www/user/"


просто пустая страница и всё :(

Comment: define('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH', '/var/www/user/');

мой вам совет, если вы в этом не разбираетесь - наймите специалиста ...